# Run a script or program when a monitor triggers in tmux?

Tags: tmux

In tmux, instead of (or in addition to) simply changing the status line when an activity/content/silence monitor triggers, is there a way to run a script or program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's been a long time since this was asked, but since this question came up in a search for a related issue, I thought I'd mention that this is now (since at least tmux v2.7) possible using "hooks".

For example:

```
set-hook alert-silence 'run-shell "my command here"'
```

There are also hooks for `alert-activity` and `alert-bell`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a tmux variable (there are several listed in the man page) and feed one or more of these variables to a script.

For example, having this in .tmux.conf:

`set -g status-right '#(echo "Hi #h")'`

will uselessly display your "Hi" followed by your machine's hostname on the right side of the status bar.

Instead of using echo, though, you could feed it to your own script that is tailored to do whatever you want based on other variables.

If you don't want any output displayed, I would think the script can spit out an empty string.

Comment: Unfortunately, the man page says that shell command status is simply run on an interval, and not in response to a monitor triggering. Passing `#F` would tell you if a monitor had triggered and not viewed yet, but it wouldn't happen right when the monitor triggered. That's probably as close as we can get at the moment, though.

Comment: You can set the status-interval to trigger every second and get it extremely close.